# Centering grid clips nested grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create layout with two columns as nested grid with left grid having dynamic number of columns/width and right column with static width. Left grid can have many columns (from 0 to n) and right grid has static width. I want to center parent of these grids horizontally but adding `justify-content: center` causes overflow to clip some content of left grid

where I want it to work as here:
https://jsfiddle.net/4o8bkdtm/17/

Where is centered to the full width of the grid parent.

##### Reproduction

```css
.grid {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  height: 400px;
  display: grid;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 400px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-1,
.grid-2 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.grid-1 {
  direction: rtl;
  grid-auto-columns: max-content;
}

.grid-1>div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-1">
    <div style="grid-column: 1; grid-row: 1;">first</div>
    <div style="grid-column: 2; grid-row: 1;">second</div>
    <div style="grid-column: 3; grid-row: 1;">third</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-2">
    static width
  </div>
</div>
```

Reproduction fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zLmxorgv/5/